# How to provide security for Spring REST API?

Tags: java, spring

API client has username and password.

In postman client selects Basic Auth and enters username and password. When request made to server postman sends BASIC AUTH TOKEN to server.

Now on server side we have only one table containing username and password. We are not maintaining any roles for client, that is why we have only one table. Now, how to resolve username and password using BASIC AUTH TOKEN. And once resolved how to compare it against username and password stored in DATABASE.

I am beginner to SPRING, Struggling to implement this for very long time.
Please help.

Comment: you go for spring security framework that gives the security for us.

Comment: I found some tutorials for this concept. But it is all role based authentication.

Comment: yes it is role based auth.

Comment: Can you tell me how to do it, without role based authentication. directly by using username and password only with database

Comment: "I am beginner to SPRING, Struggling to implement this for very long time." well you can't have been struggling for very long if you're a beginner to Spring.

Comment: You can find me as beginner by looking at my question. I think implementing spring security is basic thing :(

Answer (score 1):

you can read this topic http://www.svlada.com/jwt-token-authentication-with-spring-boot/.
it s very helpful. it  based on jwt authentication.

Answer (score 0):

Try using Spring security. Which is easy and robust. You can just enable http basic security for your application by creating a WebSecurityConfigAdapter.
https://docs.spring.io/spring-`security/site/docs/current/reference/html/jc.html#jc-httpsecurity`

If you dont want to go for Spring Security, you can write your custom implementation. Http Basic Auth token is nothing but colon seperated base64 encoded form of username and password. For Example username and password is sent as base64 encoded form of username:password.
So you can add a SecurityFilter as below.

```
public class SecurityFilter implements Filter{  
public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse resp,  
    FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {  
    String auth = httpRequest.getHeader("Authorization");
    if (auth != null && auth.startsWith("Basic")) {
        String base64Auth = auth.substring("Basic".length()).trim();
        String credentials = new String(Base64.getDecoder().decode(base64Auth),
                Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
        String[] usernamePassword = credentials.split(":",2);
    // Query to database and do authentication here using username and password. 
    //if(successfull)
    //    chain.doFilter(req, resp);
    //else
    //    return 401 error
}  

}
```